# select datediff between fields or parameter

Tags: sql, parameters, datediff

I have the following part within my select statement, which works when I write the dates, but when I send parameters it gives me an error.

This works:

```
SELECT (...unrelevant info), DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN Startdate > '14/6/2014' THEN Startdate ELSE '14/6/2014' END,   CASE WHEN Enddate < '19/6/2014' THEN Enddate ELSE '19/6/2014' END) + 1 AS AmontOfSelectedDays
```

This gives me error:

```
SELECT (...unrelevant info), DATEDIFF(DAY, CASE WHEN Startdate > @from 
THEN Startdate ELSE @from END, 
CASE WHEN Enddate < @until THEN Enddate ELSE @until END) + 1 AS AmontOfSelectedDays
```

I do this in my dataset-datatable within visual studio.

When running it within the query builder it gives me the following error:

The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect.Parameter3 ("@from"):
Data type `0F0` (user-defined data type) has an invalid user type specified.

When continuing it gives me the following warning
The `@from` variable must be declared.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. You need to `Declare` your `@from` variable.

Comment: where would I do that? And why, I never declared variables used as parameters for my select?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my answer: somehow when I changed from writing explicit dates to @from, my where clause got deleted (where startdate<@until and enddate>@from) now that I put it back in, it works